# for loop in scipy.stats.linregress

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

I am using the scipy stats module to calculate the linear regression. ie

```
 slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err 
= stats.linregress(data['cov_0.0075']['num'],data['cov_0.0075']['com'])
```

where `data` is a dictionary containing several `'cov_x'` keys corresponding to a dataframe with columns `'num'` and `'com'`

I want to be able to loop through this dictionary and do linear regression on each `'cov_x'`.  I am not sure how to do this. I tried:

```
for i in data:
    slope_+str(i), intercept+str(i), r_value+str(i),p_value+str(i),std_err+str(i)= stats.linregress(data[i]['num'],data[i]['com'])
```

Essentially I want len(x) slope_x values.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [a list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to collect all the `stats.linregress` return values:

```
result = [stats.linregress(df['num'],df['com']) for key, df in data.items()]
```

`result` is a list of 5-tuples. To collect all the first, second, third, etc... elements from each 5-tuple into separate lists, use [`zip(*[...])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
slopes, intercepts, r_values, p_values, stderrs = zip(*result)
```

Comment: When I do this it returns the values in reverse order. Ie slope should go from max value to min value rather than min value to max value.

Comment: The keys in a dict (such as `data`) have no order. In other words, `data.items()` may return the key/value pairs in any order. If you want the slopes in sorted descending order, then could sort them after the fact: `slopes = sorted(slopes, reverse=True)` .

Comment: I need them in the indexed order to put the values back into a dataframe. is that possible?

Comment: Sure, but you need to explain in your question what is the indexed order. If the order of the keys in given in a list `keys`, then you could use `result = [stats.linregress(data[key]['num'],data[key]['com']) for key in keys]`. Also note that if the order of the keys in `data` matters, then perhaps `data` should not be a dict. An ordered data structure such as a list might serve you better.

Comment: The data is in a dict from a previous function I had to do. I will just try and find another way.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do what you're trying to, but there are a couple of things you should watch out for.

First, you can't add a string to a variable name and store it that way. No plus signs on the left of the equals sign. Ever.

You should be able to accomplish what you're trying to do, however. Just make sure that you use the `dict` data type if you want string indexing.

```
import scipy.stats as stats
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {}
l = ['cov_0.0075','cov_0.005']
for i in l:
    x = np.random.random(100)
    y = np.random.random(100)+15
    d = {'num':x,'com':y}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    data[i] = df
slope = {}
intercept = {}
r_value = {}
p_value = {}
std_error = {}
for i in data:
    slope[str(i)], \
    intercept[str(i)], \
    r_value[str(i)],\
    p_value[str(i)], std_error[str(i)]= stats.linregress(data[i]['num'],data[i]['com'])
print(slope,intercept,r_value,p_value,std_error)
```

should work just fine. Otherwise, you can store individual values and put them in a list later.

Comment: @Riett when I do this I get the following error:

 
`TypeError   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-135-733714017ed2> in <module>()
      5 std_error = {}
      6 for i in data:
----> 7     slope[str(i)], intercept[str(i)], r_value[str(i)],p_value[str(i)],std_err[str(i)]= stats.linregress(data[i]['num'],data[i]['RTLnVn'])

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: @Fungie I had an error in my code, used the wrong name for std_error in one of the lines. I can't replicate your problem, however.

Comment: @Fungie I replaced my example with a minimum working example. Does it work now?